# Can't access user in api.php (But login was successful with auth()) [Laravel 5.5]

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm working with ***Laravel 5.5***. I have a problem with getting `user` in custom `FormRequest` Class when I use `api.php` routes where I make `$request`. But I logged and login was successful with `auth()`. I just searched google and other sources for find other related problems but nothing helps for solve this problem. Can anyone check my snippets. I just attached my files here.

This is `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        // appending custom middleware
        \App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class,

    ],

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'        => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic'  => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings'    => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can'         => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest'       => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'admins_only' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminsOnly::class,
    'throttle'    => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'admin_groups'=> \App\Http\Middleware\AdminGroups::class
];

    'api' => [
       'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

This is `auth.php`

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

This is my custom `FormRequest` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Ad;

use App\Models\Ads\Ad;
use App\Traits\Validation;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class AdRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use Validation;

    public function authorize()
    {   
        // #1 try to get user with Auth (gave null)
        dd(Auth::guard('api')->user());

        // #2 try to get use with auth() helper (gave null)
        dd(auth()->guard('api')->user())

        // #3 try to get just check auth()->user (gave null)
        dd(auth()->user()) or dd(Auth::user())

        // #4 try to get user with request (gave null)
        $user = $this->user('api');

        dd($user);
```

P.S. This snippets same with old project, which uses **Laravel 5.3** and works fine. I don't know what's wrong, I just about spent 10+ hours for find solution, tried all following steps which I found google, github issue forum , here and etc. blogs but nothing helped. Maybe I missed something. Thanks! :)